# I do not know how to append a list from a text file within a loop statement and then rewrite the text file

Tags: loops, append

This is what I have so far, I'm not sure if I'm on the right path but I need help nonetheless.

I have a text file called "GroceryList.txt". I want to take the information in this file and convert it into a list within my code so i can use for a loop statement.
I want the user to input items in order to make sure that they have all the items written on the list. If the user inputs an item that isn't on the list, I want to add it to the list, if the user inputs an item already on the list, I want to print a statement saying `This item is written down`.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to append to the list within the loop. At the end, i want to print the updated version of the list and add it back into the text file.
Thank you!

```py
importText=open("GroceryList.txt", "r")
contentList=importText.read()
groceryList=contentList.split()
print(groceryList)
reviewList=['Peanut', 'Grape', 'Carrot', 'Water', 'Milk', 'Egg', 'Bread']
newList=[input("Enter grocery list items")]
for i in reviewList:
  if newList in i:
    newlist.append(i)
   else: 
    print("We have this item in our list")
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct but you've few mistakes.

Firstly,
your if statement is checking if `newList` a type of list is in `i` a type of str which is simply a `TypeError` and that's supposed to be `if i in newList`

Secondly,
you've `newlist.append(i)` which indicates you made a typo as `newlist` does not exist so it should be `newList.append(i)`

So correct(working) code should be

```py
importText=open("GroceryList.txt", "r")
contentList=importText.read()
groceryList=contentList.split()
print(groceryList)
reviewList=['Peanut', 'Grape', 'Carrot', 'Water', 'Milk', 'Egg', 'Bread']
newList=[input("Enter grocery list items")]
for i in reviewList:
  if i in newList:
    newList.append(i)
  else: 
    print("We have this item in our list")
```

Please compare my solution to yours so you can see the difference.